# Trying to make an idle / incremental game in unity, but having trouble with an advanced math equation

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine

I am making an idle game inspired by Adventure Capitalist, and basically what I have is buttons that list costs, and the cash per second it gives, and how many I have of the item. I also have a multiplier button, that I want to show the stats if I click 10x or 100x, but the problem is that the item is supposed to multiply by 1.15 after each purchase. Like if I had 1 item, and bought another, the cost would go up from 1, to 1.15, then 1.15 to 1.32, etc. But I only have the formula to multiply that by my multiplier integer. So instead of it showing the increased costs after I hit 10X multiplier, it only shows the cost to be 10, instead of 1*1.15 10 times.

I hope this makes sense, because I am kind of confused myself. I just want to basically return a number for a 5X multiplier: A*1.15 = B, B*1.15 = C, C*1.15 = D, D*1.15 = E, E*1.15 = F.

I have tried a for loop returning a variable, but that didn't work also.

Comment: Use [power](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Pow.html) instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula you want is:

```
modifiedCost = baseCost * Math.Pow(multiplier, numberOfTimes)
```

For example, suppose that `baseCost` is 100 and `multiplier` is 1.15. If `numberOfTimes` is 1, then `modifiedCost` will be 1.15; if `numberOfTimes` is 2, then `modifiedCost` will be about 1.32; and so on.

Comment: Genius! Thanks @Tanner Swett. I was close, my latest attempt was: modifiedCost = * Math.Pow(baseCost * multiplier, numberOfTimes). Thanks again for the help!